# How to show last git commit of files

Tags: git

In `github` you can see the last commit of every file, how you do it using CLI only

[image: here an image to it]

the only way I found right now is using this command

```
for x in *; do printf '%s > %s\n' "$x" "$(git log --oneline -1 "$x")"; done
```

But that is inefficient.

Comment: `git log -n 1 filename`

Comment: @IvanSheigets: that's the command he's already using, for which his complaint is that it's inefficient.

Comment: @win-t I'm using a Python script to set file timestamps to the date/time of the last commit the file was modified. If you're interested in Python code I can publish it here and you can adapt it to your needs. It parses `git log` output but runs `git log` only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like git doesn't provide that functionality built-in, 
and I think it is okay for little inefficient

I hope this can be helpful for someone

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

{
  printf 'FILE|COMMIT|MESSAGE|TIME\n'
  for x in *; do 
    printf '%s|%s\n' "$x" "$(git log -n1 --format='%h|%s|%ar' -- "$x")"
  done
} | column -t -s '|'
```

[here an example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIOwt.png)